# python file throw strange error in bash script but runs perfectly by its own

Tags: python, bash, cron, raspberry-pi, gpsd

Hi I have built a gps solution on raspberry pi.

The python code works well until I wrap everything up into a bash script... then strange things happened...

so I have:
1. publish.py (this file publish the GPS data to a MQTT topic)
2. listener.py (this file listen to the MQTT topic for testing purpose)
3. job.sh (bash script to run some command the publish.py file)
4. crontab (I made a crontab to run every 10 min to run the job.sh script)

publish.py

```
from gps import *
import time
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import nacl.secret
import nacl.utils
import device

#initiate the device object
device = device.Device()

sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()


timestamp = 0
latitude = 0
longitude = 0

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("topic")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

# put the symmetricKey into box
file = open("/home/pi/Project/symmetricKey", "rb")
symmetricKey = file.readline()
box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(symmetricKey)

def getPositionData(gps):
    nx = gpsd.next()
    if nx['class'] == 'TPV':
        global timestamp
        global latitude
        global longitude
        print("##############")
        timestamp = getattr(nx,'time', "Unknown")
        latitude = getattr(nx,'lat', "Unknown")
        longitude = getattr(nx,'lon', "Unknown")
        #print "##timestamp: ", timestamp, "##Your position: lon = ", str(longitude), ", lat = ", str(latitude)

    return timestamp, latitude, longitude

def getSenseHatData():
    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    temp = sense.get_temperature()
    humidity = sense.get_humidity()
    #print "pressure: ", pressure, "temp: ", temp, "humidity: ", humidity

    return pressure, temp, humidity

def encrptyMessage(body):
    encrpted = box.encrypt(body)
    return encrpted

gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE|WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

def run():
    try:
        print ("Application started!")
        while True:
            gpsData = getPositionData(gpsd)
            senseHatData = getSenseHatData()
            dictionary = {
                "timestamp": gpsData[0],
                "latitude": gpsData[1],
                "longitude": gpsData[2],
                "pressure": senseHatData[0],
                "temp": senseHatData[1],
                "humidity": senseHatData[2]
            }
            body = json.dumps(dictionary)
            encrptedBody = encrptyMessage(body)

            print (dictionary)
            try:
                client.publish('topic', payload=encrptedBody)
            except:
                print("message is not successfully sent...")
            time.sleep(1.0)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt):
        running = False
        print ("Applications closed!")

    return body

run()
```

job.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket & #this is to start GPS socket

sleep 5

python /home/pi/Project/publish.py & #this is to run my publish.py

sleep 10

sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket & #this is to stop the socket service
```

crontab

```
*/10 * * * * bash /home/pi/job.sh
```

**The strange things are**

when I run publish.py directly, everything is working well.... but when I run job.sh, the code will throw out error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Project/publishTelemetry.py", line 123, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/pi/Project/publishTelemetry.py", line 97, in run
    gpsData = getPositionData(gpsd)
  File "/home/pi/Project/publishTelemetry.py", line 45, in getPositionData
    nx = gpsd.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/gps.py", line 287, in next
    return self.__next__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/gps.py", line 279, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
```

Do you know that if python and bash have something weird behavior like this???

thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I think, you need to keep your publish.py running right? (There is a `while True` , in your code), So instead of directly calling it from the shell script, as `python file.py` , you have to use something like screen and detach it, so that the script keeps running in the backround

Answer (score 0):

It runs exactly as it should. You start the gps service, then asynchronously start you script, 10 seconds later you stop the gps service. Once you do that, the reading loop raises a `StopIteration` to indicate that you cannot get new updates (since the service was stopped).

You can simply catch this exception and stop the job, assuming that is the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks @gerwin , I extended the 10 sec to 15 sec now because sometimes the server stops before it even retrieve any data. 

You meant to catch the exception in the gps.py code? or my publish.py code? could you be a bit more specific? thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, then, yes: if you want to gracefully handle the error case, simply wrap this line: `nx = gpsd.next()` with a try-except `StopIteration`. Then in the except clause, exit the program. Your program will behave the exact same way, but you won't have the exception log, because now you've handled that.

Comment: Thanks @Gerwin! I think the underlying issue is the GSP sensor behaves not very stable so I have to set the sleep time longer to retrieve enough data points... it really drives me crazy because when I test it, sometimes the code works, sometimes not...

Comment: As a suggestion: You could also just let the gps service run all the time, then put only the Python script in the cron and stop once you got the desired number of readings.